# Deleting lines with sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have a file data.txt like this.

```
>1BN5.txt
207
208
211
>1B24.txt
88
92
```

I have a folder F1 that contains text files.

1BN5.txt file in  F1 folder is shown below.

```
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C 
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C  
ATOM    422  C   SER A 248      70.124 -29.955   8.226  1.00 55.81           C 
ATOM    615  H   LEU B 208       3.361  -5.394  -6.021  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM    616  HA  LEU B 211       2.930  -4.494  -3.302  1.00 10.00           H 
ATOM    626  N   MET B  87       1.054  -3.071  -5.633  1.00 10.00           N  
ATOM    627  CA  MET B  87      -0.213  -2.354  -5.826  1.00 10.00           C
```

1B24.txt file in  F1 folder is shown below.

```
ATOM    630  CB  MET B  87      -0.476  -2.140  -7.318  1.00 10.00           C 
ATOM    631  CG  MET B  88      -0.828  -0.688  -7.575  1.00 10.00           C
ATOM    632  SD  MET B  88      -2.380  -0.156  -6.830  1.00 10.00           S
ATOM    643  N   ALA B  92      -1.541  -4.371  -5.366  1.00 10.00           N  
ATOM    644  CA  ALA B  94      -2.560  -5.149  -4.675  1.00 10.00           C
```

I need only the lines containing 207,208,211(6th column)in 1BN5.txt file. I want to delete other lines in 1BN5.txt file. Like this, I need only the lines containing 88,92 in 1B24.txt file.

```
Desired output
```

1BN5.txt file

```
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C 
ATOM    615  H   LEU B 208       3.361  -5.394  -6.021  1.00 10.00           H  
ATOM    616  HA  LEU B 211       2.930  -4.494  -3.302  1.00 10.00           H
```

1B24.txt file

```
ATOM    631  CG  MET B  88      -0.828  -0.688  -7.575  1.00 10.00           C
ATOM    632  SD  MET B  88      -2.380  -0.156  -6.830  1.00 10.00           S
ATOM    643  N   ALA B  92      -1.541  -4.371  -5.366  1.00 10.00           N
```

Comment: Judging from the errors you are getting from several reasonable answers, there may be some extra characters in your file data.txt.

Comment: There are no extra characters in file data.txt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk data.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
/^>/ {
    file = substr($1,2)
    next
}

{
    a[file][$1]
}

END {

    for (i in a) {

        while ( ( getline line < ("./F1/" i) ) > 0 ) {

            split(line,b)

            for (j in a[i]) {

                if (b[6]==j) {

                    print line > "./F1/" i ".new"
                }
            }
        }

        system(sprintf("mv ./F1/%s.new ./F1/%s", i, i))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '/^>/ { file = substr($1,2); next } { a[file][$1] } END { for (i in a) { while ( ( getline line < ("./F1/" i) ) > 0 ) { split(line,b); for (j in a[i]) if (b[6]==j) print line > "./F1/" i ".new" } system(sprintf("mv ./F1/%s.new ./F1/%s", i, i)) } }' data.txt
```

---

---

If you have an older version of `awk`, older than `GNU Awk 4.0.0`, you could try the following. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk data.txt
```

Contents of script.awk:

```
/^>/ {
    file = substr($1,2)
    next
}

{
    a[file]=( a[file] ? a[file] SUBSEP : "") $1
}

END {

    for (i in a) {

        split(a[i],b,SUBSEP)

        while ( ( getline line < ("./F1/" i) ) > 0 ) {

            split(line,c)

            for (j in b) {

                if (c[6]==b[j]) {

                    print line > "./F1/" i ".new"
                }
            }
        }

        system(sprintf("mv ./F1/%s.new ./F1/%s", i, i))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk '/^>/ { file = substr($1,2); next } { a[file]=( a[file] ? a[file] SUBSEP : "") $1 } END { for (i in a) { split(a[i],b,SUBSEP); while ( ( getline line < ("./F1/" i) ) > 0 ) { split(line,c); for (j in b) if (c[6]==b[j]) print line > "./F1/" i ".new" } system(sprintf("mv ./F1/%s.new ./F1/%s", i, i)) } }' data.txt
```

---

---

Please note that this script does exactly as you describe. It expects files like `1BN5.txt` and `1B24.txt` to reside in the folder `F1` in the present working directory. It will also overwrite your original files. If this is not the desired behavior, drop the `system()` call. HTH.

Results:

Contents of `F1/1BN5.txt`:

```
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C 
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C  
ATOM    615  H   LEU B 208       3.361  -5.394  -6.021  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM    616  HA  LEU B 211       2.930  -4.494  -3.302  1.00 10.00           H
```

Contents of `F1/1B24.txt`:

```
ATOM    631  CG  MET B  88      -0.828  -0.688  -7.575  1.00 10.00           C
ATOM    632  SD  MET B  88      -2.380  -0.156  -6.830  1.00 10.00           S
ATOM    643  N   ALA B  92      -1.541  -4.371  -5.366  1.00 10.00           N
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your code worked well with my example. But for large files,I don't get the correct output. It prints only few lines. If you increase the number of lines in my example you can understand the difference.

Comment: @user1606106: Hmm. I'll look into this now. Any chance at sending me those larger files? If you can, use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/home) and some sort of compression I guess.

Comment: @user1606106: I've updated the script for you. It should now work well for really large files. Please let me know if you have any problems. HTH.

Comment: when I tried your code I got syntax error. awk: script.awk:7:     a[file][$1] ^ syntax error.  awk: script.awk:18: for (j in a[i]) { ^ syntax error

Comment: @user1606106: What version of `awk` are you using? What's the output of `awk --version | head -n 1`?

Comment: The output is GNU Awk 3.1.8

Comment: @user1606106: I can confirm that the above solution will work for `GNU Awk 4.0.0` and above. Is it possible for you to upgrade to the latest version? I will think about another way to accomplish the task without using an array of arrays.

Comment: @steve "i" would be a pseudo-multi-D subscript (filename SUBSEP $6) so it should fail as written at the getline line, can't understand why it doesn't fail for you. It would fail for files under F1 whose names contain spaces. And, obviously, I'm not loving the getline :-).

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you're using the new gawk-specific true multi-D array syntax of `a[file][$1]` instead of the traditional `a[file,$1]`. That would certainly cause issues between awk versions and I'm not sure what "i" would be set to after `for (i in a)`.

Comment: @steve It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I really appreciate your attitude to help others. I will try to upgrade GNU Awk 4.0.0.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes you're right, version 4 comes with some nice bells and whistles, doesn't it? `i` would be the key in the array and `a[i]` would be the subarray elements assigned to that key. To access these subarrays, you'd simply need to loop them. I found [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arrays-of-Arrays.html) helpful. I've also added support for the older awks using `SUBSEP`. I agree `getline` is often abused and more often avoidable, but what's not to like when it's used safely? It should be fast and maintainable :-)

Comment: @user1606106: Not a problem. Glad we got it working for you :-)

Comment: @steve the getline's just redundant since awk reads all the lines in a file without it so it's like if you had a script/tool that does `WHILE read line { workon line }` and you modify it to the moral equivalent of `WHILE read line { IF some condition { WHILE read otherline { workon otherline } } }`. Even when it's safe, it's not a great approach...

Comment: simple example of the issues with the getline approach above vs the non-getline solution I posted. Ignore the initial file. Lets say you want to enhance your script to additionally print the 4th field of the 17th line of every selected file? With the getline approach you'd need to introduce a variable to count the lines read and then invoke split() whereas with the non-getline you just use FNR and $4. You could drop the "line" variable to get the split for free but then you've lost the original $0. You could create a variable to store that... Get the point? It's just a mess of workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to delete lines from the existing file, try to create a new file with only the lines you want to have:

```
cat 1bn5.txt | awk '$6 == 207 || $6 == 208 || $6 == 211 { print }' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming gnu awk, run this command from the directory containing `data.txt`:

```
awk -F">" '{if($2 != ""){fname=$2}if($2 == ""){term=$1;system("grep "term" F1/"fname" >>F1/"fname"_results");}}' data.txt
```

this parses `data.txt` for filenames and search terms, then calls `grep` from inside `awk` to append the matches from each file and term listed in `data.txt` to a new file in `F1` called `originalfilename.txt_results`.

if you want to replace the original files completely, you could then run this command:

```
grep "^>.*$" data.txt | sed 's/>//' | xargs -I{} find F1 -name {}_results -exec mv F1/{}_results F1/{} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your code worked well. But unwanted lines are printing with the output.

Comment: if you can provide a larger sample set or expand on what extra unwanted output you're seeing, I can try to make some revisions.

Answer (score 1):

This solution plays some tricks with the record separator: "data.txt" uses <kbd>></kbd> as the record separator, while  the other files use newline.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {RS=">"}
    FNR == 1 {
        # since the first char in data.txt is the record separator, 
        # there is an empty record before the real data starts
        next
    }
    {
        n = split($0, a, "\n")
        file = "F1/" a[1]
        newfile = file ".new"
        RS="\n"
        while (getline < file) {
            for (i=2; i<n; i++) {
                if ($6 == a[i]) {
                    print > newfile
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        RS=">"
        system(sprintf("mv \"%s\" \"%s.bak\" && mv \"%s\" \"%s\"", file, file, newfile, file))
    }
' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.when I am running your code I am getting error  ^ invalid char ''' in expression. How to solve this error?

Comment: Don't know. I didn't get any errors while testing. Did you cut and paste or re-type?

Comment: would fail for file names containing spaces and unsafe use of getline (not testing it's return). Also not sure if all non-gawk awks (which only allow a single character in RS) would treat `RS="\n"` as RS=newline or if some or all of them would treat it as RS=backslash. You might need to use `RS=sprintf("%s","\n")`. Finally the print should use > instead of >> (what you have would only do harm if the file existed but it's misleading at best).

Comment: True about `>>`. What about filenames with spaces? I'm using RS=> and then splitting on newlines.

Comment: It's the `system("mv")`. You need to quote where the file names will be populated  in that string.

Comment: Change the `'` quoites to `\"`s. You can't include `'`s in a `'`-delimitted script.

Answer (score 1):

This will move all of the files in F1 to a tmp dir named "backup" and then re-create just the resultant non-empty files under F1

```
mv F1 backup &&
mkdir F1 &&
awk '
NF==FNR {
   if (sub(/>/,"")) {
      file=$0
      ARGV[ARGC++] = "backup/" file
   }
   else {
      tgt[file,$0] = "F1/" file
   }
   next
}
(FILENAME,$6) in tgt {
   print > tgt[FILENAME,$6]
}
' data.txt &&
rm -rf backup
```

If you want the empty files too it's a trivial tweak and if you want to keep the backup dir just get rid of the `"&& rm.."` at the end (do that during testing anyway).

EDIT: FYI this is one case where you could argue the case for getline not being completely incorrect since it's parsing a first file that's totally unlike the rest of the files in structure and intent so parsing that one file differently from the rest isn't going to cause any maintenance headaches later:

```
mv F1 backup &&
mkdir F1 &&
awk -v data="data.txt" '
BEGIN {
   while ( (getline line < data) > 0 ) {
      if (sub(/>/,"",line)) {
         file=line
         ARGV[ARGC++] = "backup/" file
      }
      else {
         tgt[file,line] = "F1/" file
      }
   }
}
(FILENAME,$6) in tgt {
   print > tgt[FILENAME,$6]
}
' &&
rm -rf backup
```

but as you can see it makes the script a bit more complicated (though slightly more efficient as there's now no test for FNR==NR in the main body).

Comment: I'm a little confused, probably because it's getting on 1am ... but what's the point of `FNR==NR` when only one file is listed in the arguments list? and where does "tmpdir/" come from?

Comment: We start out with just one file but then as it's reading the first file it's adding file names to ARGV so after reading the first file, there are many files now to parse. "tmpdir" should be "backup", I'll fix it, thanks.

Comment: Wow that's a neat solution - I'd give it another vote if I could. Thankyou for the explanation :-)

Comment: @steve You're welcome and I just added a getline-appropriate alternative too, just for a change of pace :-).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a job for `awk`:

```
$ awk '$6==207||$6==208||$6==211 { print }' 1bn5.txt
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C 
ATOM    421  CA  SER A 207      68.627 -29.819   8.533  1.00 50.79           C  
ATOM    615  H   LEU B 208       3.361  -5.394  -6.021  1.00 10.00           H
ATOM    616  HA  LEU B 211       2.930  -4.494  -3.302  1.00 10.00           H 

$ awk '$6==92||$6==88 { print }' 1B24.txt
ATOM    631  CG  MET B  88      -0.828  -0.688  -7.575  1.00 10.00           C
ATOM    632  SD  MET B  88      -2.380  -0.156  -6.830  1.00 10.00           S
ATOM    643  N   ALA B  92      -1.541  -4.371  -5.366  1.00 10.00           N
```

Redirect to save the output:

```
$ awk '$6==207||$6==208||$6==211 { print }' 1bn5.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with just `sed` alone. You need a loop to read your file data.txt. For example, using a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First remove all possible "problematic" characters from data.txt, storing result
# in data.clean.txt. This removes everything except A-Z, a-z, 0-9, leading >, and ..
sed 's/[^A-Za-z0-9>\.]//g;s/\(.\)>/\1/g;/^$/d' data.txt >| data.clean.txt

# Next determine which lines to keep:
cat data.clean.txt | while read line; do
   if [[ "${line:0:1}" == ">" ]]; then
      # If input starts with ">", set remainder to be the current file
      file="${line:1}"
   else
      # If value is in sixth column, add "keep" to end of line
      # Columns assumed separated by one or more spaces
      # "+" is a GNU extension, so we need the -r switch
      sed -i -r "/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +$line +/s/$/keep/" $file
   fi
done

# Finally delete the unwanted lines, i.e. those without "keep":
# (assumes each file appears only once in data.txt)
cat data.clean.txt | while read line; do
   if [[ "${line:0:1}" == ">" ]]; then
      sed -i -n "/keep/{s/keep//g;p;}" ${line:1}
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.when I am running your code I am getting error "unary operator expected". How to solve this error?

Comment: Works ok for me, in my environment. But http://stackoverflow.com/a/408980/318716 suggests changing the `[` to `[[` might help, and `]` to `]]`. Does this work?

Comment: A better suggestion: replace the two `${line:0:1}` with `"${line:0:1}"`. Your `data.txt` may have a blank line, or something similar.

Comment: I've added an initial cleanup of data.txt, to remove everything except A-Z, a-z, 0-9, leading >, and ., in case some extraneous characters are breaking the script.

Comment: UUOC and would fail for files containing lines that start or end in spaces or contain backslashes or already have the word keep in them.